# Python: Why randint on a matrix keeps giving me the same rows

Tags: python, arrays, random, matrix, rows

I'm using Python 3 and with this code:

```
import random
mat = [[0]*5]*5

for i in range (0,5) :
    for j in range (0,5)  :
        mat[i][j] = random.randint(10,50)

print (mat)
```

I'm getting results like this:

```
[[26, 10, 28, 21, 15], [26, 10, 28, 21, 15], [26, 10, 28, 21, 15], [26, 10, 28, 21, 15], [26, 10, 28, 21, 15]]
```

The rows are equal each other, but the loop seems to be alright.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
mat = [[0]*5]*5
```

What that does is to create a single list of 5 zeros (`[0]*5`) and then create 5 more references to that **same list**.

The solution which gets you around this problem:

```
mat = [[0]*5 for _ in xrange(5)]
```

this creates a list of 5 zeros 5 separate times meaning that all the lists are independent.

Answer (score 4):

Because all the inner lists are actually copies of same object, so modifying one of them
will automatically affect other lists as well.:

```
>>> l = [[0]*5]*5
>>> [id(x) for x in l]
[155011468, 155011468, 155011468, 155011468, 155011468]
```

Same IDs means all indexes actually point to same object inside the list:

```
>>> l[0][0] = 1  #modifying one, changes all of them
>>> l
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Use a `list comprehension` to fix this issue:

```
>>> l = [[0]*5 for _ in xrange(5)]
>>> [id(x) for x in l]               #all lists are unique now
[155710028, 155710764, 155710700, 155710732, 155709996]
```

Works as expected:

```
>>> l[0][0] = 1
>>> l
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```